# VBA - Changing row shading when a column value changes even with filtered

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro to change the colors of rows when the values in column B change. Column A will be my controlling column using 1's and 0's, i.e. column A will stay a 1 as long as column B stays the same; whenever B changes, A will flip to a 0, and so on.

I can get it to color the rows correctly when the values in column B change, but the problem arises when I filter the data. For example: let's say I have B2-B4 set to "test1", B5-B7 set to "test2", and B8-B10 set to "test3", then I filter column B to not include "test2". Originally, the rows would be colored differently where the column values changed, but rows B2-B4 and B8-B10 are set to the same color and now they're touching since the "test2" rows are hidden.

Here's the code I used to color the rows, but it doesn't work for filtering:

```
Sub ColorRows()
    Dim This As Long
    Dim Previous As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Color As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    RwColor = Array(15,0)
    Color = 0

    For R = 2 To LastRow
        This = Cells(R, 1).Value
        Previous = Cells(R - 1, 1).Value
        If This <> Previous Then Color = 1 - Color

        Range("A" & R & ":M" & R).Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = RwColor(Color)
    Next R
End Sub
```

How can I fix it so that even after filtering the rows are colored correctly when there is a change in column values?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow! Can you post the code you have tried? That's easier for us to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this:

1.) Insert the code below as a UDF in a code module.
2.) Then put the formula in A, as A2: `=analyseVisible(B2)`.

This will compare `B`-cells to the next *visible* cell above and result in a 'rank'-counter in `A`.

Now that the counter in A in contiunous (even if rows are hidden), you can use `MOD 2` to color it with conditional formatting:

3.) Add a conditional format (from A2 for the whole table): `=MOD($A2,2)=1` and set the fill color.

If you use the filter now or change values in B, the rows are re-colored in realtime.

```
Public Function analyseVisible(r As Range) As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    If Application.Caller.Row <= 2 Or _
    r.Row <> Application.Caller.Row Then
        analyseVisible = 1
        Exit Function
    End If

    i = r.Row - 1
    While r.Worksheet.Rows(i).Hidden And i > 1
        i = i - 1
    Wend

    If i = 1 Then
        analyseVisible = 1
    Else
        analyseVisible = r.Worksheet.Cells(i, Application.Caller.Column).Value
        If r.Worksheet.Cells(i, r.Column).Value <> _
         r.Value Then analyseVisible = analyseVisible + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles the issue by checking only the used & visible rows. It works pretty well, but I was unable to figure out how to fire it when the filter changes. It also does it's comparisons directly on the values that are changing.

```
Private Sub colorRows()
    Dim this As Variant
    Dim previous As Variant
    Dim currentColor As Long

    Dim rng As Range 'visible range
    Dim c As Range ' cell
    ' pick a color to start with
    currentColor = vbYellow
    ' rng = used and visible cells
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each c In rng         ' For each cell that is visible and used
        If Not c.Row = 1 Then ' skip header row
            this = c.Value
            'some simple test logic to switch colors
            If this <> previous Then
                If currentColor = vbBlue Then
                    currentColor = vbYellow
                ElseIf currentColor = vbYellow Then
                    currentColor = vbBlue
                End If
            End If
            'set interior color
            c.Interior.color = currentColor

            previous = this
       End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Then, in the module of the worksheet that you want to colorize, call the sub from the Worksheet_Activate() event. (In reality, you probably want a different event. I mostly work with Access, so I don't really know what's available to you. I'm just trying to point you in the right direction to what I'm sure is your next question if you stick with the method you started with.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    colorRows
End Sub
```